# Синхронизировать select'ы

Tags: javascript

Как при выборе option в 'timein' отображать такой же в 'timeout' и наоборот.Тоесть выбрал "после 13" и на втором select показалось "Выезд до 13"

```
      <select id="timein" name="timein">
        <option value="12:00" selected>После 12</option>
        <option value="13:00">После 13</option>
        <option value="14:00">После 14</option>
      </select>
      <select id="timeout" name="timeout" title="Time to go out">
        <option value="12:00">Выезд до 12</option>
        <option value="13:00">Выезд до 13</option>
        <option value="14:00">Выезд до 14</option>
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("timein").addEventListener("change", sync);
document.getElementById("timeout").addEventListener("change", sync);

function sync(e) {
  var other = document.getElementById(
    (this.id == "timeout")? "timein" : "timeout");
  other.value = this.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="timein" name="timein">
  <option value="12:00" selected>После 12</option>
  <option value="13:00">После 13</option>
  <option value="14:00">После 14</option>
</select>
<select id="timeout" name="timeout" title="Time to go out">
  <option value="12:00">Выезд до 12</option>
  <option value="13:00">Выезд до 13</option>
  <option value="14:00">Выезд до 14</option>
</select>
```